# How to start React app in Laravel project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, npm, npm-start

I have a Laravel app and react app in same folder.
`npm start` is not running and gives me error "npm ERR! missing script: start"
It is running when I enter command `npm run dev` but how run only react project for development in Laravel project without building.

React files are in resources/js laravel folder

package.json is

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

I have also set start in pagkage.json but not working

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node resources/js/App.js", 
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Comment: `npm run watch` will keep watching and generating new `css` and `js` and to see those changes you need php server `php artisan serve` or any server like apache or nginx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kamles Paul `npm run watch` is working perfectly.